# INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE- Appium Eclipse Error

Tags: appium

I am trying to launch amazon.apk fron Appium(Eclispe Java/Selenium/Appium Project).    Getting Below Error message

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Remote install failed: pkg: /data/local/tmp/15dc8f05bc75fbbc3d67915f0bf9215b.apk

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)


Console Logs

System info: host: 'VEENA', ip: '192.168.2.5', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:367)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1 Please make sure you don't have the older version of your application installed.

Incase you haven't un-install then - On your Android device, go into Settings > Apps > search for amazon app > uninstall. 
Once you've deleted your application > run your test and it should install normally.

Solution #2 If this is production apk then re-install the app > than use AppInstaller to uninstall it and this should work.

Please let me know which solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if the new apk that you are trying to install is of an older version compared to the apk that you have installed on your current phone. For eg, if your phone has 1.2.3 and you are trying to install 1.2.0 which is less that 1.2.3, this error is thrown. As suggested, uninstall your current apk and try installing it again. If you are testing Amazon from Playstore, install from Playstore manually and suggest you to use appPackage and appActivity directly instead of using apk.